# Current due to motion of electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, electric-current

The radius of first orbit of hydrogen atom is $0.5 A$ and an electron is moving in this orbit with velocity $2 \times 10^6$ meter/sec, the current due to motion of electron in the orbit will be?

Comment: Hi Shruti and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, you may use $i=q/t$. You know the charge (the charge of the election).  If your current is a circular loop (since the electron is travelling in an orbit around the nucleus), how long will it take the electron to make one loop? You know that the speed is $2\times 10^6$. If you find the path length of one orbit, you can find the time of one orbit.